# Wrong element position on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Currently, I'm creating a simple video player to practice. But, I'm facing something that I never saw before, something that I tried for hours find a way to fix but I didn't make it.

Here is my code =>

```js
var left = document.getElementById('core').getBoundingClientRect().left - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  let x = ((e.clientX + window.pageXOffset) - left);
  document.getElementById("thumbnail").style.left = (x + "px");
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.core {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: auto;
}

#time {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
  color: #fff;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 12px;
  min-width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

#progressZone {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#progress{
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: auto;
  background: transparent;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: auto;
  margin: 0;
  width: 12em;
  height: 7em;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.thumbnail::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  transform: translateY(-19%);
}

#progress:hover + .thumbnail {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="core" class="core">
    <div id="time">01:14:28</div>
    <div id="progressZone">
      <input id="progress" class="range" type='range' min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0">
      <div id="thumbnail" class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is: when I hover the input bar, I'm getting wrong hovered position. After of many hours trying discover why this is happenning, I figured out that `#time` is, **indirectly**, causing this. The presence of `#time` is making the input bar probably show the wrong hover time. But I can't remove `#time` and I need the code in this structure, with `divs` wrapped. If you remove #time and test the code, you will see that the hover position will be correct.

Here is a screenshot of what I expect to happen =>

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUobw.png) (I cant yet add embed images)

I suspect that this is something related to `flex` property, and about `position` as well. But I tried everything to fix this and got no sucess. Could you please, help me understand or fix this?

Also, here is the jsfiddle link if you want => https://jsfiddle.net/9qvLd35a/

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript you take the left-value from the entire core-div. But you only need the value from the progressZone. So you can just adjust it like this: `var left = document.getElementById('progressZone').getBoundingClientRect() ...`

```js
var left = document.getElementById('progressZone').getBoundingClientRect().left - document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
  let x = ((e.clientX + window.pageXOffset) - left);
  document.getElementById("thumbnail").style.left = (x + "px");
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.core {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: auto;
}

#time {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
  color: #fff;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 12px;
  min-width: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

#progressZone {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#progress{
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: auto;
  background: transparent;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: auto;
  margin: 0;
  width: 12em;
  height: 7em;
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.thumbnail::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid rgb(200, 200, 200);
  transform: translateY(-19%);
}

#progress:hover + .thumbnail {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="core" class="core">
    <div id="time">01:14:28</div>
    <div id="progressZone">
      <input id="progress" class="range" type='range' min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0">
      <div id="thumbnail" class="thumbnail"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And as far as I can see it, this should have solved the issue. I hope I got your problem right :)